# How to edit lines of a text file based on regex conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-group, writefile

```py
import re

re_for_identificate_1 = r""

with open("data_path/filename_1.txt","r+") as file:
    for line in file:
        #replace with a substring adding a space in the middle
        line = re.sub(re_for_identificate_1, " milesimo", line)

        #replace in txt with the fixed line
```

Example `filename_1.txt` :

```
unmilesimo primero
1001°

dosmilesimos quinto
2005°

tresmilesimos
3000°

nuevemilesimos doceavo
9012°
```

The **correct output** file that I need obtiene is this:

Rewrited input `filename_1.txt`

```
un milesimo primero
1001°

dos milesimos quinto
2005°

tres milesimos
3000°

nueve milesimos doceavo
9012°
```

What is the regex that I need and what is the best way to replace the fixed línes in their original positions in the input file?

Comment: Do you have to do this in python? Using `sed` might be easier.

Comment: @MichaelM. Yes, I have to do it in python because it is part of a program that needs ordinal numbers to have that part separated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `file.seek(0)` to go beginning of the file, then write data and truncate the file. Like this:

```
import re

re_for_identificate_1 = "(?<!^)milesimo"

tmp = ""
with open("data.txt", "r+") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = re.sub(re_for_identificate_1, " milesimo", line)
        tmp += line
    file.seek(0)
    file.write(tmp)
    file.truncate()
```

The regex you want to use is `"(?<!^)milesimo"` to replace every instance of "milesimo" with " milesimo" but not at the beginning of a line.

Comment: I think the regex was blank on purpose -- the question was **What is the regex that I need**

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, didn't catch that.

Comment: This doesn't even need to be a regexp, you can just use `line = line.replace('milesimo', ' milesimo')`

Comment: @MichaelM I find a problem the the line is `"milesimo"` and this code put `" milesimo"` and it is not fine, because the space is not in the middle of 2 words, for example `"dos milesimos"`. Because trata is necessary the regex, the regex is the replacement condition

Comment: @Barmar The problem with use simple replacement is that you cant make the condition that the replacement is only when "milesimo" is after otero Word.

Comment: @SantiagoNahuelRodriguez I've updated my answer to fix that. Now the regex will only match if it is not at the beginning of the line.

Comment: It might be more appropriate to replace `(un|dos|tres|...)milesimos` with `$1 milesimos`. But then you need to enumerate all the possible numbers.